# I am looking that srchtext.send_keys("sample text") where sample text come from excel file. Put script into a loop. Loop continue till reach end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, automation

from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

srch = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#asearch > a > i')
srch.click()
srchtext = driver.find_element_by_id('txtSearch')
srchtext.send_keys('amethyst earrings')
srchbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnSearch"]/i""")
srchbtn.click()
```

driver.quit()

Comment: would you want to articulate your problem statement , well?

Comment: I have data stored in excel that has to be filled in the form on web...how not know how to get data row by row to fill in the form...I have prepare script that can fill the form automatically but I have 1000's row that all need to be filled...now how do i set that loop continue until reach the last row...and how do i set up whenver on the next loop next data get from next row

Comment: find my response below

Answer (score 0):

you may choose to use iterrows to iterate through the rows as below and pass i to the forms

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120]})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   print(row) # or as below
   print(df.iloc[index])
```